# CakePHP Pagination, how can I sort by an attribute added in afterFind?

Tags: sorting, cakephp, find, pagination

In afterFind(), I'm adding a new attribute to each record, 'distance', calculated there. I'd like to sort by this attribute.

Currently, I can sort by any other attribute except 'distance'. Is there a way to make Paginator sort by an attribute created in afterFind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, use a virtual field instead of afterFind.  The problem with afterFind is that you're calculating the distance after the database query, and you need to sort by distance in the database query in order to have the items sorted across all your pages.  The best you can do with afterfind is have the items sorted by distance within a page, but page 1 could have an item with distance 1, page 2 has an item with distance 10, and page 3 has an item of distance 2, if you get what I'm saying.

Comment: I understand - Paginate wraps find, so it can't sort the results in the find if it's already run. I don't think I could put the same functions in a virtual field. I can't think of anywhere else to put the math. Is it possible to reorder the results afterwards?

Comment: So, you could write a custom paginate function http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination that orders your results afterwards.  But again, the problem is that that will only order your results within the current page.  You would have to get all the results and sort that to have the results ordered across all pages.  At that point, you might as well not use the paginate component at all.  What exactly are you doing to calculate distance?

Comment: the afterFind looks up the search postcode, gets the latitude and longitude, then does the same for every result postcode, running a function that calculates the point to point distance between them, and adding that distance to each record as 'distance'

Comment: Think I'll have to query for all, then sort those, then drop all but those for the current page, but that could mean pulling a massive number of records for every page :/

Comment: Ah, I've done something very similar in the past.  What you should do is look up the coordinates of the locations as you are saving them, and save that to the database as well.  Then you can can create a virtual field that calculates the distance between them.  Here's what mine turned out like: `$this->virtualFields['distance'] = 3963 . ' * ACOS(COS(PI()/2 - RADIANS(90 - Retailer.lat)) * ' . 'COS(PI()/2 - RADIANS(90 - '. $lat .')) * ' . 'COS(RADIANS(Retailer.lng) - RADIANS('. $lng .')) + ' . 'SIN(PI()/2 - RADIANS(90 - Retailer.lat)) * ' . 'SIN(PI()/2 - RADIANS(90 - '. $lat . ')))';`

Comment: If the long/lat was in another table (postcode), and the foreign key for the record is stored in Retailer, you'd need Postcode.lng, Postcode.lat. Is there a way to do that in the virtual field?

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, the lng/lat for each entry are stored in another table?  I believe you can still do that, but it's a little trickier.  You'll need to do a manual join between the table you're searching and the one that holds the lng/lat, for example, `$options['joins'] = array(array('table' => 'model2', 'alias' => 'Model2', 'conditions' => array('Model2.model1_id = Model1.id')));` and then in your virtual field, I think you should be able to use `Model2.lat` and `Model2.lng` and have it work.

Comment: That's correct - I'll give a go thanks! Already posted as another question if you'd like to add that as an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463804/