# Access multiple foreign fields in a Virtual Field?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-2.4

Two tables, with the relationship set up properly in Cakephp:

Property (..., **postcode_id**,...) and Postcode (***id***, postcode, latitude, longitude).

A Virtual Field created in Property beforeFind() calculates the distance between a search postcode and the record postcode. Therefore, to get the lat/long, I need to retrieve a record from the Postcode table by the foreign key in the Property record, all within the virtual field declaration.

How can I do this? Multiple SELECTs nested within? Nested find(), which would probably be worse? I thought just using RelatedModel.fieldName would work - it doesn't.

EDIT: Property belongsTo Postcode, Postcode hasMany Property

(Using cakephp v2.4.4)

The Virtual Field in Property beforeFind():

```
$this->virtualFields['distance'] = 6371 . ' * ACOS(
    (SIN(RADIANS(Postcode.latitude)) * ' . $searchPostcode['latitudeSin'] . ') +
    (COS(RADIANS(Postcode.latitude)) * ' . $searchPostcode['latitudeCos'] . ') *
     COS(RADIANS(Postcode.longitude) - ' . $searchPostcode['longitude'] . ')
)';
```

Comment: This does not answer your question directly, but did you look into the bakery at this [behavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/zeroasterisk/2010/12/10/rangeable_behavior_find_ranged_based_on_a_lat_lon_field) that you may be able to leverage for solving distances with zip codes

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how much work would be needed for CakePHP 2 compatibility. Either way, I'm hoping there's something more general that I can use here for any calculated field with this issue, not just geographic ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working, but I had to nest another SELECT in each foreign call, which can't be the best solution. For example,

```
RADIANS((SELECT latitude FROM postcodes WHERE id = Property.postcode_id))
```

This also means that the same value, latitude, is being retrieved twice, so that's not great.

Please share a better solution if you have one!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a manual join between the table you're searching and the one that holds the lng/lat, for example, $options['joins'] = array(array('table' => 'model2', 'alias' => 'Model2', 'conditions' => array('Model2.model1_id = Model1.id'))); and then in your virtual field, I think you should be able to use Model2.lat and Model2.lng and have it work.

Comment: I do have the relationship set out as cake dictates - won't I then be joining the models twice?

Comment: Set the model's recursive property to -1 for this, and if you need other associated models, use the containable behavior instead, so that it won't attempt to get that second model again automatically.  You need to do it this way because cake will naturally get the associated model with multiple queries -- which is a problem since you need to get Model1 and Model2 in one query.  Another possible option is if it's a hasOne or belongsTo relationship between the models, you can put the virtual field on Model2 instead, since the paginator component will let you sort by directly associated models.

Comment: I have public $recursive = -1; in AppModel. I get the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Postcode.latitude' in 'field list'. Am I referencing the field incorrectly?

Comment: Post the MySQL query that it's trying, and your paginate options, please.